# PHP, remove all lines from a big string containing a specific word

Tags: php, pattern-matching

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.bigsite.com");
```

How could i go about removing all lines from string `$file` that contains the word "hello" ?

Comment: haha yes, but im asking because im sure theres a better way than i was doing it. and yes, there was :)

Answer (score 13):

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.bigsite.com");
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
$exclude = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'hello') !== FALSE) {
         continue;
    }
    $exclude[] = $line;
}
echo implode("\n", $exclude);
```

Comment: If you use `file` instead of `file_get_contents`, you can skip going over the whole thing twice (once to read it into a string, and another to `explode` the string into an array). `file` reads it directly into an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");

// remove sigle word hello
echo preg_replace('/(hello)/im', '', $file);

// remove multiple words hello, foo, bar, foobar
echo preg_replace('/(hello|foo|bar|foobar)/im', '', $file);
```

**EDIT Removing the Lines**

```
// read each file lines in array
$lines = file('http://example.com/');

// match single word hello
$pattern = '/(hello)/im';

// match multiple words hello, foo, bar, foobar
$pattern = '/(hello|foo|bar|foobar)/im';

$rows = array();

foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
        // lines not containing hello
        $rows[] = $line;
    }
}

// now create the paragraph again
echo implode("\n", $rows);
```

Comment: i need the whole line removed, not only the words.

Comment: This actually only removed instances of the word, not the lines the word appears on, as the question requires.

Comment: @CodeProtocol From the PHP Manual: "Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster." (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: @Duotrigesimal, I know that. The way you are talking is answered by others, I cannot copy paste, this is alternative solution. also `strpos` find only one word, you can match multiple with regex.

Comment: @CodeProtocol That's fair. I'm just pointing out flaws in your approach for the good of the community.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$file = file('http://www.bigsite.com');

foreach( $file as $key=>$line ) {
  if( false !== strpos($line, 'hello') ) {
    unset $file[$key];
  }
}

$file = implode("\n", $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.bigsite.com");
echo preg_replace('/((^|\n).*hello.*(\n|$))/', "\n", $file).trim();
```

The 4 patterns are for matching

- if the first line has hello
- A center line has hello
- The last line has hello
- The only line has hello

In case this are files with \r\n (Carriage return & Newline like on Windows) you need to modify this accordingly. The Trim can remove trailing and/or leading newlines